# How to set default values for a user control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I got a user control called PicturePanel.  On the mouse events (MouseDown, MouseMove, MouseUp), I have the following:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (marquee == true && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && BackgroundImage != null)
    {
          //Code to create rectangular marquee
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Class level variable `private bool marquee = false` by default.  And a public one.

```
private bool marquee = false;
public bool Marquee
{
    get { return marquee; }
    set { marquee = value; }
}
```

I even tried assigning the `false` at initialization:

```
public PicturePanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    marquee = false;
}
```

But marquee is always true by default.  If I want to turn off marquee, I have to set it through the public variable `picturePanel1.Marquee = false` in the form.  How can I make marquee false by default within the user control?

Comment: The best practice is to use default(T) where T could be any type which batches the LHS when your in confusion.
bool someValue = default(bool);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about, but if you're referring to the default value that you see in the **designer**, then you just need to add the following attribute to your property:

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool Marquee
...
```

Comment: Since you brought up the designer, I went back and checked.  I hadn't considered that existing controls that I've dragged on to the form aren't updated with changes to the user control class.  New controls that I drag on to the form have Marquee as false.

Answer (score 0):

Well, booleans are always false by default. You don't happen to have a local variable called marquee or something?

Just set a breakpoint on `private bool marquee = false;` and step through your code and you'll find it pretty quick.

Comment: No, there is only one marquee variable that I've declared at the top.  Besides, if that were true then my public variable `Marquee` wouldn't give me the expected behaviour.  I can turn marquee mode on and off with `picturePanel1.Marquee = true` or `picturePanel.Marquee = false`.  But I want the default to be to have marquee off.  And I've tried to explicitly set it to false in the PicturePanel class.

Comment: @Ryder booleans are definitely false by default. Have a look at the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be that when you use the designer to "draw" the control on the form, it might be registering the MouseDown event, setting the Marquee to true. You can prevent this by checking `this.DesignMode` in your event handler.

Example:

```
if (this.DesignMode) return;
```